# Whats the right design pattern for such a non-clearly-defined inheritance?

Tags: java, design-patterns

Assume we have a class `Car` with subclasses mini and sedan, both have same safety checks to I call a common function called safety() which is like a template. So:

```
class Car {
    safety() {
        check1();
        check2();
        check3();
        check4();
    }
}

class Mini extends Car {
    // use the safety() belonging to Car
}


class Sedan extends Car {
    // use the safety() belonging to Car
}
```

But then things change, and we have a new types and new safeties

1. `sports` needs check1, check3 and a new check5
2. `jeep`  needs check1, check4 and new check6
3. `luxury` needs check2 and check3 only

Which design patterns help us work around this issue ?

Comment: You could simply expose the check methods as protected methods, and let subclasses override safety() by calling whatever check methods they want.

Comment: Stategy http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern and Decorator http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern patterns may help.

Comment: Make the Car class abstract with these checks abstract methods and just implement those checks into proper subclasses as @JBNizet said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Forget patterns** and implement your classes in a way that fits your **use case**. In your example, I would argue, that safety is not really a property of a Car, but rather the *result* of some procedure *applied to* a Car.

```
class CrashTestDummy
{
   public Safety check(Car car) {...}
   public Safety check(Mini mini) {...}
   public Safety check(Sedan sedan) {...}
}
```

This way you can *compare* Safeties to one another, make decisions based on them, *aggregate* them or save them over time.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what the pattern is - probably [Strategy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) - but I would code it the way you think about it:

```
enum Check {

    Brakes {
                @Override
                boolean pass(Vehicle vehicle) {
                    return checkBrakes(vehicle);
                }
            },
    Lights {
                @Override
                boolean pass(Vehicle vehicle) {
                    return checkLights(vehicle);
                }
            },
    Steering {
                @Override
                boolean pass(Vehicle vehicle) {
                    return checkSteering(vehicle);
                }
            },
    Oil {
                @Override
                boolean pass(Vehicle vehicle) {
                    return checkOil(vehicle);
                }
            },
    Suspension {
                @Override
                boolean pass(Vehicle vehicle) {
                    return checkSuspension(vehicle);
                }
            };

    abstract boolean pass(Vehicle vehicle);
}

enum Vehicle {

    Car(Check.Brakes, Check.Lights, Check.Oil, Check.Steering),
    Mini(Car, Check.Suspension);

    Set<Check> checks = EnumSet.noneOf(Check.class);

    Vehicle(Check... checks) {
        this.checks.addAll(Arrays.asList(checks));
    }

    Vehicle(Vehicle like, Check... checks) {
        this.checks.addAll(like.checks);
        this.checks.addAll(Arrays.asList(checks));
    }

    public Set<Check> fail () {
        Set<Check> failed = EnumSet.noneOf(Check.class);
        for ( Check check : checks ) {
            if ( !check.pass(this) ) {
                failed.add(check);
            }
        }
        return failed;
    }
}

private static boolean checkBrakes(Vehicle vehicle) {
    return true;
}

private static boolean checkLights(Vehicle vehicle) {
    return true;
}

private static boolean checkSteering(Vehicle vehicle) {
    return true;
}

private static boolean checkOil(Vehicle vehicle) {
    return true;
}

private static boolean checkSuspension(Vehicle vehicle) {
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion very suitable would be a Visitor pattern http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern

There are two basic interfaces:

```
public interface Visitable {

    void accept(Visitor visitor);

}

public interface Visitor {

    void visit(Mini mini);

    void visit(Sedan sedan);

}
```

Example implementations of Visitable could look like this (note the accept methods):

```
public class Mini extends Car implements Visitable {

    private int miniSafetyCageCondition;

    public Mini(int breaksCondition, int miniSafetyCageCondition) {
        super(breaksCondition);
        this.miniSafetyCageCondition = miniSafetyCageCondition;
    }

    @Override
    public void accept(Visitor visitor) {
        visitor.visit(this);
    }

    public int getMiniSafetyCageCondition() {
        return miniSafetyCageCondition;
    }
}

public class Sedan extends Car implements Visitable {

    private final boolean frontAirbagsPresent;

    private final boolean sideAirbagsPresent;

    public Sedan(int breaksCondition, boolean frontAirbagsPresence, boolean sideAirbagsPresent) {
        super(breaksCondition);
        this.frontAirbagsPresent = frontAirbagsPresence;
        this.sideAirbagsPresent = sideAirbagsPresent;
    }

    @Override
    public void accept(Visitor visitor) {
        visitor.visit(this);
    }

    public boolean isSideAirbagsPresent() {
        return sideAirbagsPresent;
    }

    public boolean isFrontAirbagsPresent() {
        return frontAirbagsPresent;
    }
}

public class Car {

    private final int breaksCondition;

    public Car(int breaksCondition) {
        this.breaksCondition = breaksCondition;
    }

    public int getBreaksCondition() {
        return breaksCondition;
    }

}
```

And this could be example implementation of Visitor (note the visit methods):

```
public class SafetyVisitor implements Visitor {

    private boolean result;

    private CarBasicCheck carBasicCheck = new CarBasicCheck();

    private MiniSpecificCheck miniSpecificCheck = new MiniSpecificCheck();

    private SedanSpecificCheck sedanSpecificCheck = new SedanSpecificCheck();

    @Override
    public void visit(Mini mini) {
        result = carBasicCheck.hasWorkingBreaks(mini) &&
                miniSpecificCheck.hasDurableSafetyCage(mini);
    }

    @Override
    public void visit(Sedan sedan) {
        result = carBasicCheck.hasWorkingBreaks(sedan) &&
                sedanSpecificCheck.hasEnoughAirbags(sedan);
    }

    public boolean getResult() {
        return result;
    }
}

public class MiniSpecificCheck {

    boolean hasDurableSafetyCage(Mini mini) {
        return mini.getMiniSafetyCageCondition() > 5;
    }

}

public class SedanSpecificCheck {

    public boolean hasEnoughAirbags(Sedan sedan) {
        return sedan.isFrontAirbagsPresent() || sedan.isSideAirbagsPresent();
    }

}
```

And this is the example client code:

```
public class Client {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SafetyVisitor safetyVisitor = new SafetyVisitor();

        Mini safeMini = new Mini(6, 6);
        Mini unsafeMini = new Mini(6, 3);
        Sedan safeSedan = new Sedan(6, true, false);
        Sedan unsafeSedan = new Sedan(6, false, false);

        safetyVisitor.visit(safeMini);
        System.out.println("safeMini is safe: " + safetyVisitor.getResult());
        safetyVisitor.visit(unsafeMini);
        System.out.println("unsafeMini is safe: " + safetyVisitor.getResult());
        safetyVisitor.visit(safeSedan);
        System.out.println("safeSedan is safe: " + safetyVisitor.getResult());
        safetyVisitor.visit(unsafeSedan);
        System.out.println("unsafeSedan is safe: " + safetyVisitor.getResult());
    }

}
```

The advantage here is that you dont need to know the type of object that is being checked. So you could easily have  list of Visitable objects, that you would check all at once. In case of simple checking class like the one below its not possible:

```
public interface CarSaeftyChecker {

    boolean check(Mini mini);

    boolean check(Sedan sedan);

}
```

Comment: I would appreciate elaboration

Comment: I've edited my post providing example implementation.

Answer (score 0):

My design,

Keep safety as a separate object and differnet safeties implement the interface safety.

```
 
interface Safety
{
    boolean isSafe();
    // Each safety will have its own weightage.
    float   weightage();
}

class AirbagSafety extends Safety
{
    public boolean isSafe()
    {
        // TODO: Your impl goes here.
    }

    public float weightage()
    {
        // A constant
    }
}
```

And let the car has some standard safety features to pass government regulations,

```
 

class Car
{
    Safety[] standardSafety;  // As prescribed by government.

    public float standardSafetyPoint()
    {
        float safetyPoint;
        for (Safety s : standardSafety) { s.isSafe() ? safetyPoint + weightage(); }
        return safetyPoint;
    }
}
```

And let each car has its own safety points

```
  

class Sedan extends Car
{
    Safety[] sedanSafety;

    public int safetyPoint()
    {
        float safetyPoint = 0;
        safetyPoint += super.standardSafetyPoint();
        // do a while loop like above and calculate the specific safety point.
        return safetyPoint;
    }
}
```

This way, you have more control over safety. You can specifically design BMW safety class inheriting a lot of safety and have them in your BMW car, etc.